# Is it possible to see active users? What is being used the most?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

Just installed sharepoint into my system. I was wondering if its possible to see currently active users or most active. Which site, subsite is most popular and other kind of stuff

Comment: What version of SP are you using? If you configured Usage Service Application you can get the reports through the central admin. On the top of that SP is using IIS so any IIS traffic analytic tool can give you as well insights you need.

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2013

Comment: What about Usage Service App?

Comment: How to find that? I will try google analytics

Comment: You need to access it from the Central Administration.